# Elastic Search: How can I get results where a term appears at least x times in a phrase?

Tags: elasticsearch, match, phrase

I'm querying on a location string. The way my search works is that a location is entered as a comma separated list, and I split the list by comma and generate a location_raw query for each location, like so:

```
{
    "match": {
        "location.location_raw.synonym": {
            "query": "Boston",
            "analyzer": "synonyms"
         }
    }
},
{
    "match": {
        "location.location_raw.synonym": {
            "query": "Massachusetts",
            "analyzer": "synonyms"
         }
    }
}
```

However, this causes a problem when I have repeated terms, like "New York, New York." I get matches when the term only appears once. This is the query that's generated, which I know obviously isn't going to work

```
{
    "match": {
        "location.location_raw.synonym": {
            "query": "New York",
            "analyzer": "synonyms"
         }
    }
},
{
    "match": {
        "location.location_raw.synonym": {
            "query": "New York",
            "analyzer": "synonyms"
         }
    }
}
```

But I'm not sure how to fix it. Even if I only have one "match" query, how can I require that the term appear at least 2 times? If I search for "New York, New York" I want to get only location_raw strings that contain "New York" at least twice (like "New York, New York" or "New York, New York, New York") but not "Queens, New York".